# CPU throttling back, even after cooldown

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

Since I'm running a lot of FEM simulations on my Lenovo W520 laptop, I like to have maximum performance available. Using a nifty tool called ThinkPadFanControl, I'm able to boost my fan speed, so my CPU can run comfortably at >100% for most of the time (up to 2.9GHz on my 2.0GHz Intel i7), limited by 'normal' thermal throttling nicely to stabilize temperatures around 94°C.

However, every now and then, the CPU **suddenly throttles back to minimum (8x, so 0.78GHz) for up to ten minutes**. HWiNFO64 reports thermal throttling as `No` for all cores during those minutes; temperatures will fall well below 80°C, and all other temperatures (SMART, GPU, memory) seem to be fine as well. Performance becomes very sluggish, with visible delays in typing, switching between applications, etc.

Is this known behaviour in Intel Core i7 processors? How can I prevent or mitigate this?

In the meantime, I have updated my BIOS; I have disabled SpeedStepping so that the frequency remains below 2.0GHz, to no avail. However, I have also noticed some issues with my charger; perhaps a broken connection is causing the laptop to revert to battery saving mode, despite being connected to a charger.

**Edit:** It turned out the thermal paste was completely solidified, causing erratic behaviour - I suppose I hit some protection that is a bit more stringent than just the thermal throttling, so I was looking in the wrong direction. All is well now with new cooling paste; flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Your laptop shouldn't be getting that hot, even if you are running it 24/7, at 100% usage.  The fact its throttling back to 0.78GHz indicates a thermal problem which you should resolve.  "Is this known behaviour in Intel Core i7 processors?" - Yes; Intel designs their processors to automatically scale their frequency down in order to prevent thermal damage.  "How can I prevent or mitigate this?" - Depending on your hardware you might be able to disable this protection, but that would result in, a hard crash because the most extreme protections can't be turned off.

Comment: @Ramhound Then why is the temperature indicated to be well below 80 quickly after this happens, with thermal throttling reported to be off? Is this a thermal protection beyond what the processor reports as throttling?

Comment: I would argue that, it's well below 80, because it happened.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure I'm following you. The problem is that, even when the laptop has cooled down sufficiently, it still keeps the CPU throttled back to minimum.

Comment: @Sanchises - There is delta between, the reported temperatures reported by the sensor, and the actual temperatures of the CPU die itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Lenovo W520 from around the 2011 era?
what version is the BIOS?

I ask because I noted a cpu throttling problem that seemed independent of temp with the Lenovo x220 that was fixed with a bios update in 2011..here http://vivithemage.com/2011/09/08/lenovo-x220-bios-1-21-fixes-cpu-throttling-problem/

Comment: I updated my BIOS before asking this question, to no avail. But it is indeed from 2011.

Comment: Try going into the BIOS and find something called CPU Power Management or Intel SpeedStep and disable it. And see if you get the same problem. There is package power management in addition to thermal management. There may be firmware bugs or something.
Also, download HWiNFO64 (or 32) and click on the Sensors tab. that will show you thermal and package power management and whether it's being throttled due to package power.

Comment: Also, does your battery still charge? i.e. does the laptop work if not plugged in? I'm assuming you're plugged in above. I note Lenovo had a firmware update for their battery. Wondering if maybe your battery is reporting it can't charge http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds001322

Comment: I disabled Intel SpeedStep to no avail. Also, from my question, "HWiNFO64 reports thermal throttling as No". Battery reports everything working fine.

Comment: hmm. enigma. I'm still guessing a firmware issue. What bios version do you have? Also, there's an ECP (Embedded Control Program). Did you update with this http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds018884 

  UEFI BIOS         ECP Release
  1.43 (8BET63WW) 1.36 (8AHT42WW)

Comment: I'm assuming you're running windows 8. Or did you upgrade to windows 10?

Comment: You said HWiNFO64 reported no thermal throttling. What about any package or other throttling in it's report? I'd paste my report as an example, but that Sensors report isn't copy/pasteable without a jpeg snapshot.

Comment: Rereading your post, I note that you're running at the Turbo speed, with enhanced fan, then it gets throttled way down. I wonder if something happens due to running at Turbo ..you said "up to 2.9GHz on my 2.0GHz Intel i7), limited by 'normal' thermal throttling nicely to stabilize temperatures around 94°C."

Comment: I realize now I did not include some stuff I tried in the meantime. I did disable SpeedStepping, and it's much more stable now, running only below 2GHz. But still, there are times when it just goes to 0.78GHz for no reason. I'm suspecting perhaps some problems with my battery charger, which may be suffering from a broken cable. Perhaps some kind of unintentional DOS of my BIOS, trying to communicate with the charger...

Comment: I have read stuff about power adapters causing throttling..: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Power_Connector

...senses when power is connected, and measures resistance between central signal pin and ground. Firmware might reduce performance (battery charges slowly, processors throttle to low speed) if an insufficient supply is detected. 

What is the wattage on the power adapter? it's supposed to be a 170W 8.5A adapter for the W520. They may detect the adapter size based on the resistance between the signal pin and gnd.

Correct adapter: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd009853

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turned out my thermal paste was completely solidified, so I guess that was causing erratic behaviour.

Comment: hmm. you're saying you cleaned it off and reapplied and you're not seeing the behavior? Interesting. The thermal sensor for the cpu is on the die..so you would think it would have shown high cpu temps and thermal throttling, if the heat wasn't getting out of the cpu thru the heatsink/thermal compound.

Comment: I would think the same, hence I never thought about the thermal paste being the issue. However, perhaps there is some on-board detection against running without a heatsink altogether, and this was kicking in. Alternatively, there was some completely uncorrelated problem that solved it self on dis- and reassembling the laptop. Regardless, the problem can no longer be reproduced, and the likely candidate is crispy thermal paste. Thanks for your help.